# Error running WSGI application | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' in pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I want to deploy my project on pythonanywhere.com and tried doing it, but facing some issues. Can someone help?
[This is the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcScg.png)

[The wsgi.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Teb.png)

I'm not able to understand what is the issue! please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is "No module named flask", which means that Python cannot find the Flask framework itself.  That framework is installed on PythonAnywhere by default, but newly-created virtualenvs will not have it, so my guess is that you're using a virtualenv and haven't installed Flask into it.  To install it, use the "Start a bash console in this virtualenv" link on the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere, and in the resulting console run

Answer (score 1):

1. It is your file name. Your application file name `app.py` must be same according to your shared photo.
2. It is your flask instance. It must be same with in the `app.py` file under like:

```py
from flask import Flask

# This app instance.
app = Flask(__name__)
```

After all it is going to be work.
Please sure what you set before you run your application.

[image]

Comment: In my app.py , I've written as `app = Flask( __name__ )`, so what is the issue? Isn't it right?

Comment: Can i know your app file name?

Comment: its `app.py` itself